# Can I lay 1/2" plywood over existing subfloor that has some damage

Tags: subfloor, damage

Due to water damage I am having to replace about 1200 sq ft of flooring which was all newly installed. However, the way my floor is I'm confused on how to do this without removing the bottom subfloor. Starting from under the house (its raised 5 ft) and going up there is closed cell foam which is adhered to the 3/4" subfloor, 1/2" plywood on top of that and then 1/4" plywood underlayment and finally luxury vinyl flooring. The bottom subfloor has some damage but with laying new 1/2" plywood over it it should be stable, but I'm not sure how to lay it for the best stability. Also how do you lay it correctly where the bottom subfloor is unlevel?

Comment: What are "bad spots"? Why are you replacing the upper subfloor layer? You already had more subfloor than was required for vinyl, so I don't have any concerns.

Comment: If you have pulled up the 1/2 in sub floor can you post a photo of the " bad spots" or at least describe the damage to the 3/4 decking in detail? When you say closed cell foam do you mean spray in foam that is adhered to the 3/4 decking?

Comment: The top subfloor was removed in areas where there was water damage, rot, mold, etc.. and to see how damaged the bottom subfloor was and how far out it spread. There are huge areas where the top subfloor wasn't torn up, but for stability and to make sure there is no damage underneath we might tear it all up. The closed cell spray foam it adhered to the bottom subfloor. I'm going to post pictures in a minute

Comment: Dina, please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why the posts you made below weren't appropriate. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: I would have some concerns if you can't walk on it without risk of falling through.